# One of my 3 USB ports can automount my portable HDD, not the other 2

Tags: 10.04, usb, external-hdd

I need help.

My portable hdd can be plugged into my new ASUS N43J laptop in WINDOWS 7 from any of the 3 USB ports.

In Ubuntu, it only works with 1 port.

using 10.04 64bit.

Please advise.

## Edit:

I just realised that the port is usb3.0. Sorry for my ignorance. HOw do i get my Western Digital hdd to work in usb 3.0 for ubuntu 10.04 64 bit?

Comment: Do any other devices work on those USB ports in Linux? A thumbdrive or digital camera?

Comment: I just realised that the port is usb3.0. Sorry for my ignorance. HOw do i get my Western Digital hdd to work in usb 3.0 for ubuntu 10.04 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a solution to your problem, but I guess you have one usb2 port and 2 usb3 ports. So your HDD is only working with the usb2 port. I have the same problem, and are looking for a solution.

Here is one solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642641, to upgrade the kernel, but that did not work for me.

Edit: The solution to my problem was to enable usb3 in bios

Comment: I see. This sucks. I have given up and bought a device that allows me to have more USB2.0 ports.

I always hate the transition period from old technology to new technology.

USB right now is going through that transition period. :(

Answer (score 0):

I recall having this problem and I had to install the xhci (I belive it is called: extended host controller interface or something) driver. Sorry to not fill in the rest of this answer, but perhaps google will save you.